# Solving system of equations using matrices: How would you solve this?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, systems-of-equations

I'm trying to find a value that, when multiplied by matrix A produces matrix B, or $Ax=B$. I tried using substitution for $-0.5649 x1 + 1.0228 x2 = y$ and $-0.32 x1 + 0.58 x2 = y$, but when I checked it against the solution in R, they were completely different. The correct answer is $0.5669308$, using QR factorization. I'm not sure how to do this by hand if not by regular substitution. How would you solve this system of equations? Thank you!

\begin{equation}
A=
  \begin{bmatrix}
    -0.5649\\
    1.0228 
  \end{bmatrix}
  \label{eq:aeqn}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
B=
  \begin{bmatrix}
    -0.32 \\
    0.58 
  \end{bmatrix}
  \label{eq:beqn}
\end{equation}

Comment: This is not clear.  $x$ is a scalar?  So it just multiplies the two components of $A$.  So then we should have $x=\frac {-.32}{-.5649}=\frac {.58}{1.0228}$.  In reality, these fractions are close but not identical.  They are $0.567070786,0.566471942$ respectively.  Is this what you meant?

Answer (score 1):

To solve the least square system, you just have to solve $$A^TAx=A^TB$$

$$x=\frac{A^TB}{A^TA}$$

```
octave:1> A = [-0.5649; 1.0228];
octave:2> B = [-0.32; 0.58];
octave:3> A'*B/ (A'*A)
ans =  0.56693
```